# Growth rate of orders of perfect groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, asymptotics

Is anything known about the function $P(n)$ where,

$$P(n)=|\{ m\leq n :\text{There is a perfect group of order } m\}|.$$

Like asymptotics or a good upper bound?

Comment: Its a cool question but it lacks context

Comment: "Enumeration of finite groups" (referenced [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4807637/123905)) might address your question.  (I don't have a copy to hand.)

Comment: I wonder whether almost all perfect numbers are the orders of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ or ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ for a prime power $q$. In other words numbers of the form $q(q^2-1)$, or $q(q^2-1)/2$ when $q$ is odd.

Comment: ... or possibly even numbers of the form $p(p^2-1)/2$ with $p$ an odd prime.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you think something like $P(n)/n$ goes to $0$ might be within reach?

Comment: @DerekHolt It seems like the perfect numbers not of the form $q(q^2-1)/2$ or $q(q^2-1)/2$ are a pretty large proportion of all perfect numbers. For n<10^8 its around 0.67. So I think something else is going on. Though I did notice that the perfect numbers which are not PSL or SL orders are often divisible by "large" powers of 2. So your comment about perfect numbers with orders like $2^n * 60$ may have something to do with it. This is just a guess though.

Comment: @verret I would certainly guess that to be true, but I have no idea how you might go about proving it.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't answer the question that you asked, but if we let ${\rm Perf}(\le n)$ be the number of isomorphism classes of perfect groups of order up to $n$, then we have the bounds
$$n^{l(n)^2/108-cl(n)} \le {\rm Perf}(\le n) \le n^{l(n)^2/48 + l(n)},$$
where $c$ is a constant and $l(n)= \log_2(n)$. This is
proved in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s2-39/1/67/887064?redirectedFrom=fulltext): "Enumerating Perfect Groups" by D. F.
Holt, J. London Math, Soc. 39 (1989), 67-78.

Since there are very large numbers of perfect groups of certain orders, such as $2^n.60$, this doesn't help much with estimating your function $P(n)$.

Note that the crude estimate $n^{O((\log n) ^2)}$ is the same as for the growth rate of all finite groups. But the constant in the exponent is $2/27$ for all groups, and something between $1/108$ and $1/48$ for perfect groups.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what is known about this function, but you might be interested to know that it has (basically) been computed for small values of $n$.

[GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) comes with a library of finite perfect groups, including the function `SizesPerfectGroups` which returns a list of all integers between $1$ and $2 \cdot 10^6$ which occur as the orders of perfect groups. That list is

> [ 1, 60, 120, 168, 336, 360, 504, 660, 720, 960, 1080, 1092, 1320, 1344, 1920, 2160, 2184, 2448, 2520, 2688, 3000,
> 3420, 3600, 3840, 4080, 4860, 4896, 5040, 5376, 5616, 5760, 6048, 6072, 6840, 7200, 7500, 7560, 7680, 7800,
> 7920, 9720, 9828, 10080, 10752, 11520, 12144, 12180, 14400, 14520, 14580, 14880, 15000, 15120, 15360, 15600,
> 16464, 17280, 19656, 20160, 21504, 21600, 23040, 24360, 25308, 25920, 28224, 29120, 29160, 29760, 30240, 30720,
> 32256, 32736, 34440, 34560, 37500, 39600, 39732, 40320, 43008, 43200, 43320, 43740, 46080, 48000, 50616, 51840,
> 51888, 56448, 57600, 57624, 58240, 58320, 58800, 60480, 61440, 62400, 64512, 64800, 65520, 68880, 69120, 74412,
> 75000, 77760, 79200, 79464, 79860, 80640, 84672, 86016, 86400, 87480, 92160, 95040, 96000, 100920, 102660,
> 103776, 110880, 112896, 113460, 115200, 115248, 115320, 116480, 117600, 120000, 120960, 122472, 122880, 126000,
> 129024, 129600, 131040, 131712, 138240, 144060, 146880, 148824, 150348, 151200, 151632, 155520, 158400, 159720,
> 160380, 161280, 169344, 172032, 174960, 175560, 178920, 180000, 181440, 183456, 184320, 187500, 190080, 192000,
> 194472, 201720, 205200, 205320, 216000, 221760, 223608, 225792, 226920, 230400, 232320, 233280, 237600, 240000,
> 241920, 243000, 244800, 244944, 245760, 246480, 254016, 258048, 259200, 262080, 262440, 263424, 265680, 276480,
> 285852, 288120, 291600, 293760, 300696, 302400, 311040, 320760, 322560, 332640, 336960, 344064, 345600, 352440,
> 357840, 360000, 362880, 363000, 364320, 366912, 367416, 368640, 369096, 372000, 375000, 378000, 384000, 387072,
> 388800, 388944, 393120, 393660, 410400, 411264, 411540, 417720, 423360, 432000, 435600, 443520, 446520, 447216,
> 450000, 451584, 453600, 456288, 460800, 460992, 464640, 466560, 468000, 475200, 480000, 483840, 489600, 491520,
> 492960, 504000, 515100, 516096, 518400, 524880, 531360, 544320, 546312, 550368, 552960, 571704, 574560, 583200,
> 587520, 589680, 600000, 604800, 604920, 607500, 612468, 622080, 626688, 633600, 645120, 647460, 665280, 673920,
> 675840, 677376, 685440, 688128, 691200, 693120, 699840, 704880, 712800, 720720, 721392, 725760, 728640, 729000,
> 730800, 733824, 734832, 737280, 748920, 768000, 774144, 777600, 786240, 787320, 806736, 816480, 820800, 822528,
> 823080, 846720, 864000, 871200, 874800, 878460, 881280, 885720, 887040, 892800, 900000, 903168, 907200, 912576,
> 921600, 921984, 929280, 933120, 936000, 937500, 943488, 950400, 950520, 960000, 962280, 967680, 976500, 979200,
> 979776, 983040, 987840 ]

From this you can easily compute your function $P(n)$ for $n \leq 2 \cdot 10^6$. Here's a quick plot from Mathematica:

[image: Plot of P(n)]

Comment: One might also like https://oeis.org/A060793 (orders of perfect groups) and https://oeis.org/A231867 (number of perfect groups of each of those orders).